# Word to Markdown via pandoc: prevent line breaks in paragraphs

Tags: markdown, pandoc, cpu-word

I'm using pandoc to convert Microsoft Word to Markdown. By default, it inserts line breaks into paragraphs at the point where they wrap in the original Word document. I would rather a paragraph be converted to a single line (as my Markdown files are further processed into Madcap Flare topics). Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, pandoc inserts a newline in markdown output every 72 characters. You can change this with [an option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--wrap):

```
pandoc --wrap=none
```